# Should vents protruding through the roof be protected from weather?

Tags: venting

Should vent and air intake pipes that exit thru the house roof be left open to the elements or should they be terminated with a gooseneck to make them rain proof?

Answer (score 4):

Vent pipes no, the pipes are supposed to the set so any rain that enters, drains down the same as any water that enters the pipe from the sinks, tubs, toilets etc.

Intake pipes are only to take in air, not water and if there is a low spot in the pipe, water may eventually block the pipe like a water trap, so they need to be protected from the weather.

Comment: You'll  have more to worry in bees or birds nesting in the vent pipes, which will reduce drain capacity.

Comment: That would take one huge vent pipe to accommodate the birds and or bees. I'd like to see that happen with a 2 to 4" vent pipe.... I have never seen any bigger...

Comment: Had it happen a few times, both birds and bees on 2" pipe, bees aren't so fun to clean out.

Answer (score 0):

While weather is indeed not much of an issue for drain vents (any water coming in just continues down the drain), vents from extractor fans as well as various intakes typically need a cap to stop dirty rain water from dripping on your head as you take a shower.

The main issue with any kind of a vent is blockage due to foreign objects. Birds and other critters can easily fall down an unprotected vent opening, dying somewhere in the pipe and creating an unpleasant situation for you to resolve. There are many kinds of caps on the market to prevent this, just google "roof vent cap".